# Is it possible to use openid users as minio users?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid, identity, minio

I checked the [minio guide](https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/sts/keycloak.md#keycloak-quickstart-guide-) to connect to the identity openid, finally I connected to the minio console window by Keycloak service users, but I failed to use the same username and password in the api and execute the show bucket request through postman.
Is there a way to define a user's openid and allow access to all minio features for that user?

I tried to fix the problem with different openid services like Okta, KeyCloak, Google, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get temporary tokens after the OpenID handshake for your users, once you have the STS (session tokens) you can use them to make S3 API calls.

https://github.com/minio/minio/tree/master/docs/sts read here on how to do it programmatically

Edit: More detailed documentation is available now at https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/identity-access-management.html